# PDF to Black and White TIFF conversion using PDFBox looses quality

Tags: pdfbox, graphics2d, javax.imageio

I have written a program that reads pages of a pdf file using PDFBox api and sends the BufferedImage to the following method that converts it to black and white. Then my programs writes it to TIFF files using FilesUtils.

```
private BufferedImage toBlacknWhite(BufferedImage imageBuffer) {

        BufferedImage bw = new BufferedImage(imageBuffer.getWidth(),
                imageBuffer.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);

        if (imageBuffer != null) {
            Graphics2D g2d = bw.createGraphics();
            g2d.drawImage(imageBuffer, 0, 0, null);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        return bw;
    }
```

The problem I am having is that the output TIFF files are loosing major portions of image and are of very poor quality.  Please suggest me a way to improve the quality of the output image.

Original Image:

[image: Click here to view Original image]

Output Image:

[image: Click here to view Output image]

Thank you.

Comment: If you want a black and white image (1 bit) instead of a grey scale one, you should be able to set the threshold (the value to decide if a pixel is black or white) somehow. Otherwise you can preprocess the image making it darker.

Comment: You mention PDFBox but haven't posted the code. Have you tried to render the PDF to a bitonal image? Both the 1.8 and the 2.0 versions allow this. (I'm not saying that it will be successful. Bobs comment is correct too)